# How to log into a web service with php post request

Tags: php, json, web-services, rest, post

So i need to gain access to a web service containing some json, but to do so I was told to make use of PHP POST method to first log into the web service. I was giving an array with 3 types/values.

```
{
  "Username":"user",
  "password":"1234",
  "LoginClient":"user"
}
```

I have been searching all day for a solution, but have come up short :(.

Any advice or push into a right direction would be much appreciated. 
Hope I have explained this clearly enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do as follows:

```
$url = 'http://yourDomain.net/api/auth/';
$data = array('Username' => 'user', 'password' => '1234', 'LoginClient' => 'user');
$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data),
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($opts); //Creates and returns a stream context with any options supplied in options preset.
$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

var_dump($response);
```

Or you could read about CURL as another option to make POST requests.

Comment: boolean false :( maybe my URL is wrong ? 

I am supposed to first get a User GID back. Forgot to mention that.